# for loop variable optimization in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, optimization

Which is faster in following two code snippets? and Why?

Declared loop index variable outside the `for` statement:

```
size_t i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{

}
```

and

Declared loop index variable within the `for` statement:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{

}
```

Comment: In the first example you're initialising variable 'i' twice, you don't need to do that.

Comment: You can compare the resulting assembler code on for example https://godbolt.org/ and check yourself if they are equal and look up differences when they occur.

Comment: _"Which is faster..."_ you need to measure.

Comment: if you call function from single thread, then declaring loop counter as local static variable for function will save you 2 operations with stack (push, pop) per function call. Only you can measure if it will have any impact (number of function calls)

Comment: Look at the assembly code and/or benchmark. It's the only way to be sure. (Though in this case I see no reason there could be any difference.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither, they are equivalent and will yield the same machine code.

(The compiler will remove the redundant initialization of `i` twice from the first example.)

Where a variable is declared has very little to do with performance and memory use.

`for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)` is usually considered the most readable.

`for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` has the advantage that you can use the `i` variable after the loop is done - which makes most sense when the number of iterations is variable.

Comment: Being able to "use the `i` variable after the loop is done" is not necessarily an advantage.

Comment: @Peter it _is_ not an advantage, but it _can_  be one.

Comment: @Peter I was thinking of cases such as `for(size_t i=0; i<length; i++) { str[i] = whatever; if(bad) break; } str[i] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that on the fist one, i is a global variable, and the second one is a local variable only for the loop.

Comment: There is no such thing as _global-use variables_. There are _global_ variables, but here `i` is not global either in the first case. Enhance your question, you are on the right track.

Comment: @MichaelWalz If you want to be picky, there is no such thing as "global variables" either. The C language has scope and linkage, the formal term would be "file scope variable with external linkage".

Comment: Well, try to do this:

`for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
   //do some stuff
}

printf("%d",i);`

Thats a local variable for the loop. If you declare it outside, you will be able to use it on another part of the code..